# The term 'Write-ChocolateyFailure' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: installation, package, chocolatey

So I'm trying to install yasm on Windows 11 with Chocolatey, but an error occurs, does anyone know how to solve this error?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> choco install yasm
Chocolatey v1.2.0
Installing the following packages:
yasm
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading yasm 1.2.0... 100%

yasm v1.2.0
yasm package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
The package yasm wants to run 'chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
Note: If you don't run this script, the installation will fail.
Note: To confirm automatically next time, use '-y' or consider:
choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation
Do you want to run the script?([Y]es/[A]ll - yes to all/[N]o/[P]rint): Y

WARNING: Url has SSL/TLS available, switching to HTTPS for download
Downloading yasm 64 bit
  from 'https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/releases/yasm-1.2.0-win64.exe'
Progress: 100% - Completed download of C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\yasm\tools\yasm.exe (779.5 KB).
Download of yasm.exe (779.5 KB) completed.
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\yasm\tools\yasm.exe
ERROR: The term 'Write-ChocolateyFailure' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
The install of yasm was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\yasm\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - yasm (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\yasm\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

I couldn't find a solution on the internet, so I asked here.

Answer (score 5):

This happens because you are trying to install a package that still uses a syntax that is no longer supported in Chocolatey CLI. You have two options to resolve this issue.

The first and best option is to try contacting the package's maintainer and ask them to update the package to follow modern standards of how a package should be written.

The second option that will fix your current issue is to install a compatibility package to reintroduce removed helpers that are no longer supported.
You can install this package by running: `choco install chocolatey-compatibility.extension` and then try installing the yasm package again.

Answer (score 2):

The package uses helpers (`Write-Chocolatey-Failure`) that have been deprecated for some time and subsequently removed. To restore the functionality you can use the [`chocolatey-compatibility.extension`](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/chocolatey-compatibility.extension#files) package.

However, two things:

1. The package is trying to write a failure message, so something is likely broken with the package.
2. The package was last updated in 2013 so YMMV with the software it's downloading working at all.